# Looking for a specific term related to "ram tables"

Tags: c++, ram

In my intro to C++ class, my teacher instructed us to begin using what he calls "ram tables."  It's a grid that allows you to see how variables may or may not share memory locations with others (in value and reference parameters and such).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5129928/Photo%20Oct%2016%2C%202%2006%2008%20AM.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/amltkdtvc7b6m22/photo%20oct%2016%2C%2012%2043%2047%20am.jpg?dl=0

I've searched the term "ram tables" and "memory tables" with loads of variations and find nothing.  Is there another name for these?

I know this is a silly question.  But I'm not entirely sure about how to use them when programs get more complex, so I'm trying to find some videos or text reviews on how to use them properly.  We are well into functions, which I understand when I build them myself, but reading someone else's foreign code might get confusing, so these tables offer a little bit of clarity on when variables change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're going to have to ask the teacher what he means. Have you discussed concepts like heap and stack yet? How about pointers? These tables of his may be some device that leads up to a real concept.

Comment: Unknown concept... The drawings is useless...

Comment: I probably will have to.  I wasn't sure if it was a universal concept that most C++ teachers teach or if it was something cooky he cooked up.  He's very old school and uses a lot of outdated terminology, even when referencing super simple things.  And no, we have not learned about heap or stack, and by pointers, do you mean reference values?  Values used as the output of the function that point to another variable to store the data?

Comment: I apologize for not including context in the main question, here is a problem and the table.  Pardon my poor writing.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5129928/Photo%20Oct%2016%2C%202%2006%2008%20AM.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ask your teacher what he means by that. I have never heard it like this. What else did he tell you about C++ so we can understand what subject he was talking about? Maybe he wanted to show you how variables and others are allocated through memory?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what he is trying to show us, and I understand the concept in general, when working with variables and side effects, but it starts to get a little more confusing for a beginner when using functions and reference values.  His tests are pretty brutal and all use very generic variable names that makes it hard for a dyslexic person (myself) to hand trace through them.  Anyway, appreciate the help.

Comment: From the description of yours, i think he probably drew a table for you to understand how memory allocation happens in C++. If you didn't understand it in depth yet, which is normal for a beginner, you can ask him to explain to you, or you can search through web, or read a book ("c++ primer" is a good one). Happy to help :) Accept answer and upvote if you want!

Comment: I don't know why I didn't use this for my main photo.  Here's the problem and he just wanted the output, but he used the table when going over it in class.  I apologize for my poor handwriting

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5129928/Photo%20Oct%2016%2C%202%2006%2008%20AM.jpg

Comment: You should study! And you will understand these pretty easily. This exercise is pretty simple actually. It shows how the variables go from a function to the main program, how memory allocates them, and also how putting a reference changes it. I think he will talk to you about the different kind of types you will use in C++, how they are used in functions and the changes in the background when these types have a reference(&), did he talk about calling by value and reference? The types that exist in C++?

Comment: Yes, we learned about value and reference parameters, values are input into a function and reference is output, but can be input occasionally, its just difficult because my teacher is fast and expects us to understand and have it memorized after the first time it is tough (doesn't review anything)t.  He's not the worst teacher I ever had, just not the best, which isn't ideal for learning something as difficult (to me at least) as a programming language.  I can handle bad teachers in upper level writing classes or math, but its difficult when doing something you've never done before :/

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I have one of these teachers in my university. Look, if you want to actually learn C++ while also studying in your school, i would suggest that you download a book from the internet,like the one i suggested in previous answer, and take it from the start at your own pace, i think soon you will understand these things in deep because this one covers c++ in a nice depth with full explanation for beginners! Programming is a fun thing !

Comment: I will definitely check that book out.  Thanks.  I do enjoy programming.  I haven't had much of an issue with anything this far.  Learned the very basics, to variables, to side effects, to loops.  I have built about 30 or 40 programs for my class and some for myself (just for practice) and haven't had real issues with the homework.  Got the highest in the class on the first exam (93 :)), which I did not expect at all, so I have been enjoying it thus far.  Just a few things screw with my head.  I'm over-analytic and end up screwing things up.  I'll check that book out.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :) Accept answer if you want!